# phonegap-plugin-contentsync what happens to the files after sync?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

This is the plugin in question:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-contentsync

It seems like this plugin does an excellent job wrapping up, and caching remote assets (css and js files) for me.  But, two questions for what happens to the files after a sync happens.

1) After killing the app and rebooting the device, it seems the files are persisted.  Is there some guaranteed timeframe for how long these assets are cached for?

2) The css/js that I'm caching update every once in a while, so the app polls and downloads new assets when necessary.  If the cached content is permanent, what's going to happen after this caching process has happened *a lot*?  I'd prefer not to take up tons of space on the device.

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on the platform. On Android, for example, they would persist until either your space runs out or you clean app the app cache data. They are stored in the cache dir, judging by source code:

   ```
   // Production
   String outputDirectory = cordova.getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
   ```

Here you can take a look how it is actually stored - http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

2. Again, you should check the implementation for each platform, but the Android one seems to be cleaning up properly the outdated files.